# Question reagarding convention of iterated integral in Lebesgue integral

Tags: probability-theory, lebesgue-integral

When someone writes,

$$\int _A\mu_1 (dx_1)\int_{x_1+x_2\in B}\mu_2(dx_2)=\int\int_{x_1\in A,x_1+x_2\in B}\mu(dx_1,dx_2)$$

Does the first notation really mean  $\int_A \int _{x_1+x_2\in B}\mu_2(dx_2)\mu_1(dx_1)$?

If I literally interpret the first formula, $x_1$ should be a random variable, so the equation doesn't seem to make sense. Is it a convention to write what variable we integrate on in the front?

Comment: One convention is typographical: the double (as opposed to iterated) integral is usually written as $$ \iint_{x_1\in A,x_1+x_2\in B}\mu(dx_1,dx_2) $$ rather than as $$ \int\int_{x_1\in A,x_1+x_2\in B}\mu(dx_1,dx_2) $$ The LaTeX and MathJax code is `\iint`. $\qquad$

Comment: $\ldots\,$or sometimes it's this: $$ \iint\limits_{x_1\in A,x_1+x_2\in B}\mu(dx_1,dx_2) $$ `\iint\limits_{x_1\in A,x_1+x_2\in B}\mu(dx_1,dx_2)`

Comment: The first notation means exactly what you wrote down afterwards. It is very similar to the common abbreviation of $$\int_X \int_Y f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy \,\mathrm dx$$ by $$\int_X \,\mathrm dx\int_Y f(x,y)\,\mathrm dy$$

Comment: @MaximilianJanisch when I looked at the first notation it just looks like the product of two formula, the first one being constant and the second being the variable with respect to $x_1$ (since we integrate on $x_2$)

Comment: Oh I see! It's clear now. Thank you very much. Despite its convenience, I still wonder if it would make any confusion in other contexts

Comment: @jk Ahhh I see. It is not a product but instead indeed iterated integration just written slightly differently .

Comment: Ive seen a different convention: just one symbol of integral is needed if an integral is not iterated so the double integral and the iterated are exactly the same, that is, it usually writes $\iint f(x,y) \mu_1(dx) \mu_2(dy)$ to represent the iterated integral, and $\int f(x,y) \nu(dx,dy)=\int f d\nu$ to represent the not iterated integral (maybe for $\nu=\mu_1\otimes \mu_2$)